# Word to mean unwise/foolish coming from the idea of being untravelled?

Tags: norse, etymology

I remember reading somewhere that there is a word in old Norse for unwise/foolish that etymologically refers to someone who's not travelled or left home. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably thinking of Icelandic *[heimskur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heimskur)* "stupid, foolish", which comes from Old Norse *heimskr* "foolish, silly; who has never been from home" (from ON *heima* "home"). It appears frequently in Norse sagas, sometimes in the intensive form *allheimskr* "very stupid". A famous instance of this is the saying *"Engi er allheimskr, ef þegja má"* ("No one is a total fool, if one knows when to be silent") in the *Saga of Grettir the Strong*.

I am not aware of an opposite word relating wisdom with being well-travelled, though.

Comment: There's Ingvar the Far-Travelled, (Old Norse: *Yngvarr víðförli,*) but the name is indeed not associated with being wise, as his entire army was eradicated on his last journey.